# Which is better to store data a database or internal storage?

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I just finish learning about SQlite database and i need to implement what i have learnt to a note application and display those notes in a grid view 
so my question is. Which is better way to save my notes in a database or in a file in the internal storage of the device and when to use each one of them?

thanks

Comment: The only one who knows is you.

Comment: i'm still learning so how can  i know ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this case internal storage of the devices is ment to save files, the sql database is what you are looking for due the description of your project.
There are several ORM for doing this:
 - Sugar Orm
 - DAO by Green Robot
 - Realm

There is always being a native way for working with SQL, it is called ContentProvider. However, there is a new aproach called, ROOM which is also native and more oriented to standard Models rather than using a cursor as the previous.

Comment: thanks, but can you tell me when to use internal storage to store my data

Comment: I would say never: The only data ment to be stored using internal storage are files.